# SQL Server: Insert Values Into One Table Based on Two Tables' Data

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables with the same name in two different databases. `TableA` in `DatabaseA` contains a column `ServerName`, while another `TableA` in `DatabaseB` contains the `ServerId` column. I have a third table `TableB` in `DatabaseB` that contains `ServerId` and `ServerName`, and I want to map the `ServerName` in `DatabaseA`, and its `ServerId` in `DatabaseB`, to `DatabaseB`'s `TableA`.

For example ...

In `DatabaseA`:

`TableA`:

```
ServerName
  MyServer
  HisServer
  HerServer
```

In `DatabaseB`:

`TableB`:

```
ServerId | ServerName
1          MyServer
2          HisServer
3          HerServer
```

I want to map the *ServerNames* to the *ServerIds* and insert the Ids into *DatabaseB's TableA*.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete script.

```
USE master;
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'DatabaseA')
    DROP DATABASE DatabaseA;
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'DatabaseB')
    DROP DATABASE DatabaseB;
CREATE DATABASE DatabaseA;
CREATE DATABASE DatabaseB;
GO
USE DatabaseA;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA (
    ServerName  sysname     NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO dbo.TableA VALUES (N'MyServer');
INSERT INTO dbo.TableA VALUES (N'HisServer');
INSERT INTO dbo.TableA VALUES (N'HerServer');
SELECT * FROM dbo.TableA;
GO
USE DatabaseB;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA (
    ServerID    smallint    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.TableB (
    ServerID    smallint    NOT NULL,
    ServerName  sysname     NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO dbo.TableB VALUES (1, N'MyServer');
INSERT INTO dbo.TableB VALUES (2, N'HisServer');
INSERT INTO dbo.TableB VALUES (3, N'HerServer');
SELECT * FROM dbo.TableB;

-- "I want to map the ServerNames to the ServerIds and insert the Ids into DatabaseB's TableA."

INSERT INTO dbo.TableA (
    ServerID
)
SELECT bb.ServerID
FROM DatabaseA.dbo.TableA   AS aa
JOIN DatabaseB.dbo.TableB   AS bb
  ON aa.ServerName = bb.ServerName;

SELECT * FROM dbo.TableA;
```

And the output:

```
ServerName
-------------
MyServer
HisServer
HerServer

ServerID ServerName
-------- -------------------
       1 MyServer
       2 HisServer
       3 HerServer

ServerID
--------
       1
       2
       3
```

Comment: Marking as answer since you helped me find a slightly easier solution. :-)